# Animate to left:100% if draggable element is 60% off screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element that is draggable and I am trying to make it complete off screen, by animating it to left:100%, if it is 60% off the right edge of the screen. Meaning 40% or less is visible.

I know my if condition for detecting if 60% or less is hidden is working because an alert inside it happens.

However, my calling to a custom function that only does the jQuery animation does not happen.

Here is a JS Fiddle that recreates my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/bccQh/1/

If you drag the element to the right, it fades out. So that proves that the `handleOpacity()` custom function is working. The if condition for detecting if the element is 60% or more off-screen works because the alert, which is currently commented out, fires, when the condition is true. But the calling of the second custom function `slideLeft()` does not happen, which is right after the alert.

Any ideas why the custom function is not happening and how I can get it to happen?

Here is my code:

```
$('#tabViewWindow').pep({
    axis:'x',
    useCSSTranslation:false,
    drag:function(ev, obj){
    if(obj.dx>0 && obj.$el.offset().left>=$(window).width()*0.6){
        slideLeft(ev, obj);
    }
    handleOpacity(ev, obj);
},
});
function handleOpacity(ev, obj){
    var opacity = 1 - (parseInt(obj.$el.css('left'))/$(window).width());
    obj.$el.css('opacity', opacity);
}
function slideLeft(ev, obj){
    obj.$el.animate({left:'100%'});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pep uses jQuery `animate` to change the position of the element as it's being dragged. When you call `slideLeft`, you're still dragging it, so Pep's `animate()` will keep kicking in and overriding the `animate` call in `slideLeft`.

The solution is to stop Pep once you call `slideLeft`. Looking at Pep's docs, you can set a `stopEvent` property when you call `.pep()` and then trigger it in `slideLeft`. Like this:

```
$('#tabViewWindow').pep({
    axis:'x',
    useCSSTranslation:false,
    stopEvents: "stopPep", // <---- Stop when we get a "stopPep" event
    drag:function(ev, obj){
        if(obj.dx>0 && obj.$el.offset().left>=$(window).width()*0.6){
            slideLeft(ev, obj);
        }
        handleOpacity(ev, obj);
    },
});
function slideLeft(ev, obj){
    obj.$el.trigger("stopPep"); // <---- Tell Pep to stop here!
    obj.$el.stop().animate({left:"100%"});
}
function handleOpacity(ev, obj){
    var opacity = 1 - (parseInt(obj.$el.css('left'))/$(window).width());
    obj.$el.css('opacity', opacity);
}
```

### [Here's the Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bccQh/10/)

Pep.js docs here: https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.pep.js/

Comment: When #tabViewWindow is dragged so 60% of it is off screen, Pep stops successfully, but the animation does not happen. I am trying it in your fiddle.